An issue to combine the logic of axios post request function with logic of function that adds new row to table (React, Primereact Data Table)
I am newbie to React and Primereact and i wish to create a function that will add new empty default row to my Primereact data table and at the same time make an axios post reqest of this row to the server.
So, i have two functions. First adding new row to the table:
const handleAddRow = (): void => {
    const newRow: any = {
      id: colorGroups.length + 1,
      rowValue: "",
      rowColor: "",
      rowAnnotation: "",
    };
    setColorGroups((prevList: any) => [...prevList, newRow]);
    const val = { ...{ [`${colorGroups.length + 1}`]: true } }
    setEditingRows(val);  
    };

Second - making an axios post reqest:
 const handleSubmit = async (event: DataTableRowEditCompleteEvent) => {

    console.log(event)
    console.log(refName.current?.value)
    try {
      const response = await postApi(event.newData as ColorRowGroupsDto);
      console.log(response.data)
      onSubmit()
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating post:", error);
    }
  };

Usage i need:
<div> <Button onClick={unitedAddPostFunc} /> </div>

Unfortunatly, i have no idea how to make a fuction that will unite logic of both functions that i have.
Thanks a lot to everyone, who can help with this!
